# How to change the content-single-product.php page with my custom html

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to display my custom html code on product page, I have created the child theme and copied the files of woocommerce. Now I want to implement my custom html code for that page.

Here is my custom code

```
<section id="aboutus-section" class="content-section">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="main-title">
                            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                <h1 class="text-uppercase">ART BY MONA LIND</h1>
                                <h3>$150 - <a herf="https://www.definitepossibilities.com/hosting-clients/monalind/checkout/"> Checkout</a></h3>
                                <hr/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                            <img class="img-responsive pull-right" style="margin-left: 20px; margin-bottom: 15px;" src="https://www.definitepossibilities.com/hosting-clients/monalind/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/Abstract-2-1.jpg" alt="Capturing  the light  and  the  natural  elements  of  life." />
                            <p>Art is a diverse range of human activities in creating visual, auditory or performing artifacts (artworks), expressing the author's imaginative, conceptual idea, or technical skill, intended to be appreciated for their beauty or emotional power. </p>
                            <p>Many argue that art cannot be defined. ... Art is often considered the process or product of deliberately arranging elements in a way that appeals to the senses or emotions. 
                                <br/> It encompasses a diverse range of human activities, creations and ways of expression, including music, literature, film, sculpture and paintings.
                                <br/><a herf="https://www.definitepossibilities.com/hosting-clients/monalind/checkout/"> Purchase this for $150</a>

                                </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
```

This is how I want it to look:

[image]

Here is my `content-single-product.php` template code:

```
<?php defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

/**
 * Hook: woocommerce_before_single_product.
 *
 * @hooked wc_print_notices - 10
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product' );

if ( post_password_required() ) {
    echo get_the_password_form(); // WPCS: XSS ok.
    return;
}
?>
<div id="product-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php wc_product_class(); ?>>

    <?php
        /**
         * Hook: woocommerce_before_single_product_summary.
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_show_product_sale_flash - 10
         * @hooked woocommerce_show_product_images - 20
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary' );
    ?>

    <div class="summary entry-summary">
        <?php
            /**
             * Hook: woocommerce_single_product_summary.
             *
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_title - 5
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_rating - 10
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_price - 10
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_excerpt - 20
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart - 30
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_meta - 40
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_sharing - 50
             * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::generate_product_data() - 60
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary' );
        ?>
    </div>

    <?php
        /**
         * Hook: woocommerce_after_single_product_summary.
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs - 10
         * @hooked woocommerce_upsell_display - 15
         * @hooked woocommerce_output_related_products - 20
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary' );
    ?>
</div>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product' ); ?>
```

Comment: Add your code you just put your html here, here people will help you to solve the bug but won't give you the full code. So first show your effort to implement this.

Comment: i'll happy to help but i need to understand few thing first: are you going to have only pic for each products? the checkout link what exactly do you the functionality to be do you want it when the customer click on that link they will be redirected immediately to checkout  with only one item in cart ?  so you don't want to allow to purchase more than one item?

Comment: @kashlo. Hi thank you for helping me. I want a different image for all the product. I want to directly checkout the product with one item.